Initialized accounts aren't getting recognised when testing on localnet using anchor
I'm storing a pubkey using a setter function and trying to fetch it using a getter function. This works as expected on solana playground but locally when i try testing on anchor and fetch it, it returns 11111111111111111111111111111111 though the account is initialized. I tried testing after running solana-test-validator and anchor test --skip-local-validator but it still isn't recognizing the already initialized data account.
Storing the caller as the owner
pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<InitializeContext>) -> Result<()> 
   {
       let owner_account = &mut ctx.accounts.owner_account;
       let owner_init_account = &mut ctx.accounts.owner_init_account; 
       require! (!owner_init_account.owner_initialized, ErrorCode::AlreadyInitialized);
       owner_account.owner_pubkey = ctx.accounts.payer.key();
       owner_init_account.owner_initialized = true; 
       emit!(OwnerEvent{
           owner: owner_account.owner_pubkey.key()
       });
       Ok(())
   }

Fetching the owner and emitting
 pub fn get_owner(ctx: Context<GetOwnerContext>) -> Result<()> 
    {
        let owner_account = &mut ctx.accounts.owner_account;
        msg!("owner:getOwner: {}",owner_account.owner_pubkey);
        emit!(OwnerEvent{
            owner: owner_account.owner_pubkey.key()
        });
        Ok(())
    }

This works perfectly fine on solana playground. But not locally on anchor,
import * as anchor from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { Program } from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { SolanaContracts } from "../target/types/solana_contracts";
import { publicKey } from "@coral-xyz/anchor/dist/cjs/utils";
import { PublicKey } from '@solana/web3.js'
const {expect} = require('chai'); 


describe("solana-contracts", () => {
  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  anchor.setProvider(anchor.AnchorProvider.env());

  const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();

  // Get the contract using ABI
  const contract = anchor.workspace.SolanaContracts as Program<SolanaContracts>;

  const payer = provider.wallet as anchor.Wallet;

  const [owner_account_pda,bump1] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [Buffer.from("owner")], 
    contract.programId
  );

  const [owner_int_account_pda,bump2] =  PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [Buffer.from("owner_init_account")], 
    contract.programId
  );

  const [funds_handler_account,bump3] =  PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [Buffer.from("funds_handler_account")], 
    contract.programId
  );

  let funds_handler = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();

  describe("Initialize:",()=>{
    it("Should initialize", async () => {
      const tx = await contract.methods
          .initialize()
          .accounts({ 
            ownerAccount: owner_account_pda,
            ownerInitAccount: owner_int_account_pda,
            payer: payer.publicKey, 
            systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
           })
          .signers([payer.payer])
          .simulate();
        console.log("Your transaction signature:", tx);

        const tx2 = await contract.methods
        .getOwner()
        .accounts({ 
          ownerAccount: owner_account_pda,
          payer: payer.publicKey, 
          systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
         })
        .signers([payer.payer])
        .simulate();
        const events = tx2.events;
        const ownerEvent = events.find(event => event.name === "OwnerEvent");
        console.log("Owner:", ownerEvent.data.owner.toString());
        console.log("Tx1 events:", tx.events);
        console.log("Tx2 events:", tx2.events);
        console.log("Off Chain PDA:",owner_account_pda.toString());
        console.log("Tx2 raw:", tx2);
    });
  });
});


could you try splitting the two ixs into their own it blocks and calling test again

@Jimii Yes that's how i had the tests initially, in two different it blocks, one to set and another to get. I clubbed it into one single it block hoping it would fix but still facing the sane issue

Let me try it on my end

Thanks a lot!!!

This is just a guess, but since there's both owner_account and owner_init_account, is it possible that only owner_init_account is getting initialized, and not owner_account?
Also, note that if you create an account without transferring lamports into it, the account will get deleted by the runtime. So it's also possible that the account is getting allocated and assigned, but without the lamport transfer, and getting cleaned up after the transaction.
